# Wordpress Help - Making a link populate on lower section of the page

Tags: php, hyperlink, wordpress

Wordpress Help - Making a link populate on lower section of the page

I have a simple image Carousel slider i just want to be able to click the image and have the post associated with the link appear at the bottom of the same page below the divider anyone have a trick or tip on hot to accomplish this?

Here is what im working on http://tinyurl.com/kajjcxs

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have completely understood this but here goes
You could try something like this, if I have understood what you are trying to do:

```
<ul class="slides">
   <?php // custom post query asuming you have a slider post section
    query_posts(array(
            //custom post type name
            'post_type' => 'hp_slides',
        //how many sslides to show
            'showposts' => 6
            )
        );
        // if slides available loop through
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

       <li>
      <!-- ADD PERMALINK TO TITLE/LINK SECTION-->
    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_hps_custom_meta', true );?>">
                <h2 class="slider-title ">
                    <?php the_title();?>
                </h2>
            </a>
            <!-- ADD PERMALINK TO IMG-->
            <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_hps_custom_meta', true );?>">
                <?php echo bootstrapwp_autoset_featured_img();?>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php // end of post loop.
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe I should ask it differently.. What I had in mind was if I had 4 images and they were all href or linked how do I populate the end url of those links on the same page just towards the bottom or second half of page but before the footer?

Comment: Sorry still not sure I get what you are trying to do. Are you trying to set the correct links to the Quick links Section?

Comment: No im just using the slider with .jpgs that are going to be hyperlinked to urls / posts I just want the populated url or post to appear in the lower section of the page

Comment: Ok so just under the dashed/dotted line?